# Comparing an unlimited number of values taken from a 2D array to see which element has the largest sum

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to produce a program that will check the highest sum value of a 2D array.Then it needs to compare each value against each other to output which is the largest of all the sums for each position in the array.

I'm able to do this for a set number of elements but i would like to do this for an unlimited number of elements depending on how many elements the user inputs.

```
Person = [123,321,213]

TotalMorn =[[3,5,6,4,5,3,7],
            [2,1,1,2,3,4,5],
            [3,4,5,6,7,6,5]]

TotalAft =[[8,7,6,2,6,7,5],
           [4,3,2,3,4,3,2],
           [1,1,1,1,2,3,1]]

def WeeklyTotal(K):
    Total = 0
    for j in range(7):
        TotalM = TotalMorn[K][j]
        TotslA = TotalAft[K][j]
        Total = TotalM + TotalA + Total
    return Total

Total1 = WeeklyTotal(0)
Total2 = WeeklyTotal(1)
Total3 = WeeklyTotal(2)

if Total1 > Total2 and Total1 > Total3:
    print 'Person', (Person[0]), 'Has produced the most profit with ', Total1
elif Total2 > Total1 and Total2 > Total3:
    print 'Peron', (Person[1]), 'Has produced the most profit with ', Total2
elif Total3 > Total1 and Total3 > Total2:
    print 'Person', (Person[2]), 'Has produced the most profit with ', Total3
```

Comment: How does this code work ? `TotalMorn` and `TotalAft` are not defined. And by the way, keep your variable names **lower-case**.

Comment: @IMCoins I've just not included the 2D arrays.

Comment: This is not a well explained question. Instead of pasting your code, try explaining what exactly it is you want. Give an example of the 2D array and what maximum sum means for you.

Comment: @Julien the 7 is fixed because its a weekly record of profit. Its the second part where i am comparing the totals that i need it for an unlimited number

Comment: @SilverSlash you are correct I re-read my question and have changed it. I think this is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you want to do is find the max value in the array WeeklyTotal?

```
maxIndex, maxValue = 0,0
for i in range(0,len(WeeklyTotal)-1):
    if WeeklyTotal[i] > maxValue :
        maxValue = WeeklyTotal[i]
        maxIndex = i
print 'Person ',Person[maxIndex],' Has produced the most profit with ',WeeklyTotal[maxIndex]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Like me, you can see what the problem is at a higher level than just a programming language. Unfortunately, for your input to Stackoverflow to be really useful to current and future readers, it would be much better written in python. If you can, somehow, produce an answer in python I'd like you to replace the current answer with that.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you either need to bind *person* to his *totalScore*. You would then look for the maximum score value, and so you would have the person with the maximum score affiliated with this value, such as...

```
arr = [('John', 15), ('Sue', 13), ('Jack', 20), ('Tom', 5)]    
print max(arr, key = lambda x:x[1])
# outputs : ('Jack', 20)
```

Here, you have bound the **score** to the **person** into a **list of tuples**. You asking *max* function to look for the highest value using the second element of each tuple (that's what `key = lambda x:x[1]` means).

In your example, where data would be formatted such as...

```
people = ['John', 'Sue', 'Jack', 'Tom']
scores = [15, 13, 20, 5]
```

... you might want to use a function to determine the **index** of the highest value, doing :

```
#   We set the highest score at the beginning as the first value, and save the index.
curr_score = scores[0]
saved_index = 0

#   We then iterate through scores, not looping through the first item, as its index
#   is already saved. We set the start of the index to `1`.
for index, score in enumerate(scores[1:], start=1):
    if score > curr_score:
        #   We save the new highest score.
        curr_score = score

        #   And keep its index.
        saved_index = index

#   At the end of the loop, we saved the maximum value index, and can use it
#   on `people` array.
print people[saved_index]
#   It will output the person with the highest score.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short solution using some python idioms:

(Thanks to IMCoins for reminding me about `max(a, key = lambda...`)

```
people = [123,321,213]

morning =[[3,5,6,4,5,3,7],
            [2,1,1,2,3,4,5],
            [3,4,5,6,7,6,5]]

afternoon =[[8,7,6,2,6,7,5],
           [4,3,2,3,4,3,2],
           [1,1,1,1,2,3,1]]


def makeTotals(people, morning, afternoon):
    return [(p,sum(m+a)) for (p,m,a) in zip(people, morning, afternoon)]

allTotals = makeTotals(people, morning, afternoon)

print(max(allTotals, key = lambda x:x[1]))
```

Output:

```
(123, 74)
```

The `makeTotals` function `zip`s up the arrays to align each person with their morning and afternoon scores and `(p,sum(m+a))` creates a `tuple` of the person and their total.

The call to `max` uses the `key = lambda x:x[1]` parameter (thanks @IMCoins) to pull out the tuple with the largest sum of morning and afternoon scores.

Answer (score 0):

how about a 'one-liner' (with line breaks and added whitespace for readability)

```
Person = [123,321,213]

TotalMorn =[[3,5,6,4,5,3,7],
            [2,1,1,2,3,4,5],
            [3,4,5,6,7,6,5]]

TotalAft =[[8,7,6,2,6,7,5],
           [4,3,2,3,4,3,2],
           [1,1,1,1,2,3,1]]


print('Person %s Has produced the most profit with %s'
      % max(zip(map(sum,
                    zip(map(sum, TotalMorn),
                        map(sum, TotalAft))),
                Person))[::-1])

Person 123 Has produced the most profit with 74
```